# Relative import correction without sys or os

Tags: python, python-3.x

I've read almost all of the solutions for fixing relative imports and none of them seem to work. Here's my current structure:

```
structures
\ containers
  \ queue.py
\ trees
  \ binaryTree.py
```

I want to import the queue in to my binary tree file but I'm getting slammed with relative import issue. I tried `__init__.py` but that doesn't seem to solve the relative import issue. Is there a solution to this? (I'm on Python 3.3.x)

Edit:

This is my import statement

```
from .containers.queue import Queue
```

and the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "binaryTree.py", line 1, in <module>
    from .containers.queue import Queue
SystemError: Parent module '' not loaded, cannot perform relative import
```

Comment: Can you put a code example of how you're doing the import, and the error message you're getting?

Comment: @RamiroBerrelleza Added in the import statement and error.

Comment: Are you running `binaryTree.py` as a script or importing it from somewhere else? If its a script, different rules apply!

Comment: @tdelaney I'm running it as a script for testing, I might put a test file higher up so the imports work...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Running a package module as a script is an "interesting" experience. By default, scripts are not part of packages and don't know anything about relative imports. The assumption is that the script is running in an installed environment and it is using absolute imports. `distutils` for example, puts them in a different directory when you install a package.

If your script is buried in your package distribution, it can trick the system by adding the parent directory of its package directory to `sys.path` and doing absolute imports. This is dangerous because now all directories peer to the package dir are potential python modules.

[pep 366](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0366/) defines a way to do relative imports in a script:

> When the main module is specified by its filename, then the **package** attribute will be set to None . To allow relative imports when the module is executed directly, boilerplate similar to the following would be needed before the first relative import statement:
>
> if **name** == "**main**" and **package** is None:
>       **package** = "expected.package.name"
>
> Note that this boilerplate is sufficient only if the top level package is already accessible via sys.path . Additional code that manipulates sys.path would be needed in order for direct execution to work without the top level package already being importable.

But its still awkward in my opinion. Hopefully somebody has a cleaner way to do this, but this is what I think you need:

```
if __name__ == "__main__" and __package__ is None:
    # name package for relative imports
    __package__ = "structures.trees"
    # add package dir to python path
    import os
    import sys
    pkg_parent = os.path.abspath(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), "../.."))
    sys.path.insert(0, pkg_parent)
    # ...and import
    import structures.trees

from ..containers.queue import Queue
```

But you still have a problem. If your package imports `binaryTree`, python thinks its a different module than your script so everything (including side effects) is duplicted.

Comment: I'm going to mark this as correct, based on the principle, but I think it's kind of a frustrating thing. I understand relative imports are unsafe, but so are pointers, and C++ still allows those.

Comment: Relative imports are safe for package modules. The challenge is that when the module is run as a script, its no longer in a package. The "unsafe" part is only needed if the top level package isn't importable and you have to fiddle with `sys.path`. There you run the risk of peer directories being treated as modules when they shouldn't be.

Comment: Right, I understand the principle of script vs module but it feels like the interpreter is babying me to keep from something breaking... Par for the course with Python I suppose, occasionally too much abstraction from the nitty gritty.

Answer (score 1):

```
 from ..containers.queue import Queue
```

Comment: Same issue unfortunately... it's probably something I can't fix because Python has decided relative imports are the devil...

Comment: Do you have `__init__.py` in all three directories (`structures/__init__.py`, `structures/containers/__init__.py`, and `structures/trees/__init__.py`)?

Comment: @DylanLawrence - that should work. Do you have `structures/__init__.py`, `structures/containers/__init__.py` and `structures/tree/__init__.py`? Are you in the parent of `structures` (or its in the python path)?

Comment: @tdelaney I am in `structures/tree` I'll try adding a `__init__.py` file in this directory as well as in another spot I haven't tried yet.